# How to use pivotConfig in Cube.js?

Tags: javascript, recharts, cube.js

My `resultSet` looks like this:

```
0: Object { "Error.type": "A", "Error.criticity": "ORANGE", "Error.count": 10 }
​​
1: Object { "Error.type": "B", "Error.criticity": "ORANGE", "Error.count": 8 }
​​
2: Object { "Error.type": "B", "Error.criticity": "GREEN", "Error.count": 6 }
​​
3: Object { "Error.type": "C", "Error.criticity": "ORANGE", "Error.count": 5 }
​​
4: Object { "Error.type": "C", "Error.criticity": "GREEN", "Error.count": 1 }
​​
5: Object { "Error.type": "A", "Error.criticity": "GREEN", "Error.count": 1 }
​​
```

I would like to pivot it to get this:

```
0: Object { "Error.type": "A", "ORANGE": 10, "GREEN": 1}
​
1: Object { "Error.type": "B", "ORANGE": 8, "GREEN": 6 }
​
2: Object { "Error.type": "C", "ORANGE": 5, "GREEN": 1}
```

Can I use [tablePivot](https://cube.dev/docs/@cubejs-client-core#result-set-table-pivot) to do this? If yes, how to set [pivotConfig](https://cube.dev/docs/@cubejs-client-core#types-pivot-config)?

The final goal is to render this formatted `resultSet` as a [stacked barchart with Recharts](https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/StackedBarChart).

---

I have tried:

```
resultSet.tablePivot({
                x: ['Error.type'],
                y: ['Error.criticity', 'Error.count'],
              })
```

which returns

```
0: Object { "Error.type": "A", "Error.criticity": "ORANGE", "Error.count": undefined }
​
1: Object { "Error.type": "B", "Error.criticity": "ORANGE", "Error.count": undefined }
​
2: Object { "Error.type": "C", "Error.criticity": "ORANGE", "Error.count": 5 }
```

and

```
resultSet.tablePivot({
                x: ['Error.type'],
                y: ['Error.criticity', 'measures'],
              })
```

which returns

```
0: Object { "Error.type": "A", "Error.criticity": "GREEN", "Error.count": 1 }
​
1: Object { "Error.type": "B", "Error.criticity": "GREEN", "Error.count": 6 }
​
2: Object { "Error.type": "C", "Error.criticity": "GREEN", "Error.count": 1 }
```

In both cases I lose some information.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need a `pivotConfig` like this:

```js
resultSet.tablePivot({
  x: [ 'Error.type' ],
  y: [ 'Error.criticity', 'measures' ]
})
```

The pivoted result will look like this, which is pretty much what you expect it to be, right?

```js
[
  {Error.type: "A", ORANGE,Error.count: "10", GREEN,Error.count: "1"},
  {Error.type: "B", ORANGE,Error.count: "8", GREEN,Error.count: "6"},
  {Error.type: "C", ORANGE,Error.count: "5", GREEN,Error.count: "1"}
]
```

You can read more about `pivotConfig` in Cube.js [documentation](https://cube.dev/docs/@cubejs-client-core#types-pivot-config).